# Class not find in Framework

Tags: ios, swift

Created a framework with NSObject class , build successfully.But after importing the framework , I am not able to access the class inside the framework.

```
public class DetectMotion:NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
}
```

Steps for creating framework

1.Create a new project "cocoa touch framework"

2.Import class "DetectMotion" in my case

3.Edit scheme set to "build" & build the project.

4.Import the framework from finder in main project.

Comment: Is the class header set as public or project?

Comment: @AdamRichardson updated the question

Comment: You might find this blog helpful http://www.enekoalonso.com/articles/creating-swift-frameworks-for-ios-osx-and-tvos

Comment: @Saurabh Can you tell the whole process how you created i you will create wrong then you won't be able to access

Comment: Did you embeb the framework?

Comment: @BhupatBheda I have updated the question

Comment: @BhupatBheda followed the same  , everything works fine for normal class , but with nsobject class I face the above issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have any method name for location updates , make it public & then try it will work